# Connecting a company embedded camera to Raspberry Pi

Tags: connectors

I have a proprietary camera that has a 28 pin CSI-2 interface (Connector used in camera - FH41-28S-0.5SH(05) by Hirose). Is there any possibility by which I can interface it to the Raspberry Pi 4 module which has a 15 pin CSI connector?

I tried looking for options and I found a MIPI CSI-2 to USB 3.0 camera adapter by Cypress.

(Link: https://www.cypress.com/products/ez-usb-cx3-programmable-mipi-csi-2-usb-30-camera-controller).

Is there any way I can use this for my application? Or are there any other options available?

Comment: You can use a generic USB cam, so it is a question of whether that's what the adapter provides.  *However* (someone may come along to confirm this), I believe the CSI "standard" is just about a form factor, not a full device protocol as with USB.  Ie., that that camera uses a CSI-2 connector does not indicate anything about *how*.  If that's the case then, sans a reverse engineering team, you are very likely out of luck.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. The camera that I have has an adapter available from Basler company. But, it says that it is compatible with Jetson Nano. I am still trying to figure out if I can use that with Raspberry Pi or not. 

Reference link for the adapter: https://www.baslerweb.com/en/embedded-vision/embedded-vision-portfolio/embedded-vision-kits/daa2500-60mci-nvjet-nvdk-addon/